# Why numpy treats really small numbers as zeros?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm working on an optimization task. consider "sphere benchmark function" in two dimensions.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
x = y = 0
X = np.array([x, y])
cost = np.sum(X**2)
print(cost) # zero
```

The cost of function would be zero where x and y are zero. however consider this example:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([-6.5333928195191023e-163,  2.7628829205465545e-163])
Y = X**2 # [0, 0]
cost = np.sum(Y) # zero
print(cost) # zero
```

The cost shouldn't be zero, but it is. Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal floating point precision will truncate your numbers to zero. If you really want to use values so small you can do:

```
X = np.array([-6.5333928195191023e-163,  2.7628829205465545e-163], dtype=np.longdouble)
Y = X**2 # [0, 0]
cost = np.sum(Y) # zero
print(cost) # zero
>> 5.0318743766791623303e-325
```